# Google sheets with slow formulas - are they persisted between openings?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet with multiple googlefinance formulas as well as with importhtml from Yahoo, and it's very, very slow.

So the question - if I wait for the loading all this data, will I see loaded data on next sheet opening, of it will be loaded for hours again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are that your spreadsheet will recalculate all those formulas each time you re-open the spreadsheet.

The [official documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515) no longer gives a definite answer, but it used to tell that the `googlefinance()` function refreshes every two minutes. The `importhtml()` function refreshes once an hour.